# Torsion subgroup of $y^2=x^3+4x$

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am trying to find the torsion subgroup
$E(\mathbb{Q})$ of the elliptic curve $E: y^2=x^3+4x$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ which apparently is $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ according to exercise 4.9 of the book "Rational Points on Elliptic curves" by Silverman and Tate. But the only integer points of $E$ that I could find are $(0,0), (2,4)$ and $(2,-4)$. Apparently, $P=(2,4)$ is the generator of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ but the $x$-coordinate of $P+P$ is $x([2]P)=0$. So, how is $P$ a generator of the torsion subgroup of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ as mentioned [here](https://planetmath.org/examplesoftorsionsubgroupsofellipticcurves)?
If someone could point out what I am missing here and what is the fourth point of the torsion subgroup of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The fourth point is the point at infinity! I.e. the identity. You have $[2]P = (0, 0)$, which is a 2-torsion point, but is not the identity.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Then why is $P$ mentioned as a generator?

Comment: Because it is a generator! $(0, 0) = [2]P$, $(2,-4) = [3]P$ and $\mathcal O = [4]P$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 could you convert that comments as an answer?